# Prove the following for $n\geq5$ , where $p_i$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

p<sup>3</sup><sub>n+1</sub> < p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>....p<sub>n</sub>

What I did was I was able to see that p<sup>2</sup><sub>n+1</sub> was always much smaller than p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>.....p<sub>n-1</sub> but  p<sub>n+1</sub> was definitely bigger than  p<sub>n</sub>. So how can I prove that the product of p<sup>2</sup><sub>n+1</sub> * p<sub>n+1</sub> <
(p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>....p<sub>n-1</sub>) * p<sub>n</sub>

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398525/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking to prove

$$p_{n+1}^3 \lt \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for $n \gt 5$. Note [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) gives

$$p_{n+1} \lt 2p_{n} \lt 4p_{n-1} \lt 8p_{n-2} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus,

$$p_{n+1}^3 \lt (2p_{n})(4p_{n-1})(8p_{n-2}) = 64(p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n}) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For $n = 5$, \eqref{eq1A} becomes

$$13^3 = 2179 \lt 2(3)(5)(7)(11) = 2310 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

so it's true. For $n = 6$, \eqref{eq1A} becomes

$$17^3 = 4913 \lt 2(3)(5)(7)(11)(13) = 30030 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

so that is also true. For $n \ge 7$,

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i \ge (p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4)p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n} = 210(p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_{n}) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $210 \gt 64$, combining \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq6A} gives \eqref{eq1A} is also true for all $n \ge 7$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but is there any way of proving this without the Bertrand's postulate ?

Comment: @AdhirajSinghBrar You're welcome. In one way or another, you need to have some sort of bounds being used for the prime numbers. Betrand's postulate, although relatively "crude" for estimating (since, especially for larger primes, it gives a quite poor estimate), is fairly straightforward & simple to use. An alternative is to try to use other bounds, such as what's shown in the [Approximations for the $n$th prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) Wikipedia article section, but these tend to be generally more difficult to use.

Comment: Ohk Thanks i just asked that because i didn't knew Bertrand's Postulate but now i know Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a bit of motivation, so you can solve questions like these on your own next time.

It would be nice to be able to prove this by induction. In this case, we'd multiply
$$ p_{n+1}^3 < p_1 p_2 \dots p_n $$
by $p_{n+1}$ on both sides to get
$$ p_{n+1}^4 < p_1 p_2 \dots p_n p_{n+1} .$$
If we knew that $p_{n+2}^3 < p_{n+1}^4$, then we'd be done.

Fortunately, this is true. This follows from [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) for sufficiently large $p_{n+1}$ (which holds because we have $n \geq 5$).

In fact, I believe this argument can be used to prove
$$ p_{n+1}^k < p_1 p_2 \dots p_n $$
for any nonnegative $k$, for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Is there anyway to prove that without the Betrand's postulate ?

Comment: Intuitively, the reason why this statement is true is because the primes don't increase too quickly. If suddenly, $p_{n+1}$ was much larger than $p_n$, then it would no longer be the case that $p_{n+1}^3 < p_1 \dots p_n$. Bertrand's postulate gives us this quantitative estimate by saying that $p_{n+1} < 2 p_n$, i.e. the primes don't grow too quickly. So any proof of this problem will have to invoke some statement about how quickly the primes grow (not necessarily Bertrand's postulate—it's just very well known so that's why the other answerer and I both used it).