# A formula for all coprimes to 30

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's known that there is no formula for prime numbers (I mean, formula for prime numbers, and **not for the number of them**).
One can ask : what about a formula for all **coprimes** of a natural number N ? (Again, I mean a formula which gives all coprimes of N, and **not the formula for the number of them**.)
So far I couldn't find any such formula in number theory textbooks (or exercise books).
So I was puzzled when I saw in a math olympiad book the following formula (without proof) :
**f(k) = 10k** - **14**[**k/2**] + **6**[**k/8**] + **1** ,
which gives (for natural **k** >= 0) **all coprimes to 30** :

k=0,   f(0) = **1**
k=1,   f(1) = **11**
k=2,   f(2) = **7**
k=3,   f(3) = **17**
k=4,   f(4) = **13**
k=5,   f(5) = **23**
k=6,   f(6) = **19**
k=7,   f(7) = **29**
k=8,   f(8) = **31**
k=9,   f(9) = **41**
................
................
k=14, f(14) = **49**
................
................

How can such formula be derived ? I tried to derive it by means of congruences, residue classes, Bezout's Identity for coprimes, and more - but to no avail.
Thanks in advance,
J.Grody .

Comment: Without speaking to that particular formula, one observation is that the sequence you want is a union of arithmetic progressions, 8 of them in this case.  So it’s not surprising there is a closed form.

Comment: There is a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.1127) that explains one way to find a formula. It won't find that one, though, as it finds formulas for increasing sequences. And I don't know how complicated a function you get with that approach.

Comment: Essentially it's representing the coprimes to $30$ as a union of two AP's $\,6n+1\,$ & $\,6n+11,\,$ i.e for $\,k<8\,$ it sends even $k$ to $\color{#c00}{3k+1}$ and odd $k$ to $\color{#0a0}{3k+8},\,$  i.e. the base values are

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
k&0&2&4&6& 1&3&5&7\\ \hline
f(k)&\color{#c00}1&\color{#c00}7&\color{#c00}{13}&\color{#c00}{19}&\color{#0a0}{11}&\color{#0a0}{17}&\color{#0a0}{23}&\color{#0a0}{29} \\ \hline\end{array}\qquad $$

and it shifts these values by $30$ for greater $k,\,$ i.e. $f(8q+k) := 30q+f(k)\ \ $

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398399/242) that $30$ is the largest natural such that all smaller coprimes $> 1$ are prime