# Find all natural numbers $n\ge2$ that satisfy this condition : any integer $m>1$ that is less that $n$ and relatively prime with $n$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers $n\ge2$ that satisfy this condition : any integer $m>1$ that is less than $n$ and relatively prime with $n$ is prime.
Here's what I found:for any integer $k>1$ , there exists a prime number between $k+1,k+2,...,2k-1$ but I don't know how this can help

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Surely you have tried to find some such numbers, no?

Comment: Start with a few small example $n$, say $n=4,5,6,7,...$.  Any obvious patterns?

Comment: Dupe of [this prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398399/242)

Answer (score 2):

The only numbers in this sequence are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24, and 30. This is entry [A048597](http://oeis.org/A048597) in the OEIS. You can easily check that these numbers satisfy this condition.

---

Here is a proof of the fact that no number greater than $30$ can satisfy the required condition. This is taken from Uspensky's and Heaslet's Elementary Number Theory Book. Suppose that $n$ satisfies the hypothesis and let $p_k$ be the greatest prime not exceeding $\sqrt{n}$ so that $p_k^2\leq n<p_{k+1}^2$. Then $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k$ divide $n$. Indeed, if some $p_i$ didn't divide $n$ then $n$ is coprime to $p_i^2\leq n$, which is composite. So $p_1p_2\dots p_k\leq n$ and this implies that
$$p_1\dots p_k<p_{k+1}^2,$$
however by [Bonse's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality) this inequality can be satisfied only for $k\leq 3$, hence $n<p_4^2=49$. One can check that there are no numbers between 30 and 48 satisfying the condition.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer. Are you sure there is no way to establish the numbers greater than $30$ that satisfy it?

Comment: @Mike fair enough! I expanded the answer to include a proof.

Comment: Much better, thank you!