# Prove or disprove : All of the generators greater than $1$ of $\Bbb Z_{60}$ are prime.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

I know that generators of  $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ have the form of {$k:\gcd(60,k)= 1$} . by brute force, i found that $\gcd(60,49) = 1 $and $49$ isnt prime. thus this statement would be false. However, is there a more efficient way to do this than brute force? also, is there an intuition of why this statement would be false? at first glance, I was sure that it was true, but I just didn't know how to prove it thus I started looking for counterexamples.

Comment: Note that any such $k$ would have to be the product of primes $>5$ and that $7$ is the least such prime, so $7^2$ is the smallest composite candidate.

Comment: @lulu why would it be greater than 5

Comment: Because $2,3,5$ all divide $60$.

Comment: Apparently we're only to consider the numbers from $0$ to $59$, or something like that? If that implied requirement is ignored, an easy one would be $60^2-1 = 3599$.

Comment: [$30$ is the largest integer with that property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398525/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:  Since $2\times 3\times 5$ divides $60$, any $k$ relatively prime to $60$ must be the product of primes $>5$.

The least such prime is $7$ so $7^2=49$ is the least composite number prime to $60$.  The second least is $7\times 11=77$ but that's greater than $60$ so $49$ is the only composite generator amongst $\{1,\cdots, 59\}$.